# does file size effect the speed of vba execution?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complex Excel workbook with hundreds of macros.  All runs well.  It is 9mb in size.  when I add additional sheets (they are complex charts), the file size jumps to 14mb.  This wouldn't be a problem, but some code runs very very slowly.  In particular, this is a copy sequence that copies around 60 cells from one sheet to another.  It usually happens in around 5 seconds, but when the file size becomes 14mb, the code takes around 60 seconds...intolerable.  deleting the sheet fixes the problem.  the copy sequence has no connection whatsoever to the sheet that I delete.  What am I missing?

Comment: Consider toggling  settings: `application.screenupdating=false`, `application.calculation=xlManual`, and `application.enableevents=true`. Just make sure to set those back to false at the end of your VBA. Those will keep the screen from updating, the application from updating formulas, and will keep any worksheet or workbook vba events from firing while your code is executing.

Comment: Thanks. But it's nothing like that all the settings are as you describe the common denominator seems to be the file size

Answer (score 0):

Macros run Slow (#slowmacros)

```
« Turn off calculation and screen refresh while macro is running.  Be sure to restore settings when the macro ends.  Some supposedly reset automatically but later releases tend to require you to reset.  Macros may terminate abnormally so don’t use without that thought in mind.  The examples below do not save current settings and restore them but assume normal usage is in effect.

Screen flickering is usually the result of bad coding, but turning off Screen Updating will eliminate the blinking, and speed up a macro.  Turning off calculation can have a more dramatic effect on improving performance.  Use of Special Cells and restriction to used range will greatly improve coding.

Turning off ScreenUpdating and Calculation are the easiest changes to implement.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      '    ooo   Your code here   ooo
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    Prior to XL97 (Excel 5 and Excel 97) use
    Application.Calculation = xlManual          'prior to XL97
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic     'prior to XL97
                alternative coding: restores previous settings:

      Dim savCalc As Long, savScrnUD As Boolean
      savCalc = Application.Calculation
      savScrnUD = Application.ScreenUpdating
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      '    ooo   Your code here   ooo
    done:
      Application.Calculation = savCalc
      Application.ScreenUpdating = savScrnUD

I always want calculation on and there are too many bad macros that fail and macro of my own that fail during testing so I use the version on the left above.  The code on the right above is more correct but prone to problems of leaving calculation off.

For most VBA actions, you don’t have to select the sheet or cell.  Look for such coding to be reworked/removed, you might even be able to remove the need to suppress screen updating if the appearance of the screen is not changed. (Brian Wilson Example: 2000-12-28)

Are there any Worksheet_Change events.

Related to last row problems, macros can take forever to run if they loop through all possible columns and rows instead of restricting activity to the used area.   Examples where such failures commonly occur:  deleting rows with certain content,  inserting rows or columns, selecting an entire column and macro processes entire column instead of cells in the active area.

In a test of one macro adding DIM statements appeared to increase time 30% contrary to good coding practices.  Nevertheless, by dimensioning variables you simplify code writing and maintenance and avoid some additional problems.  Turning off screenupdating saved about 12%, but turning off calculation saved an additional whopping 75%.

Use SpecialCells to reduce selection to cell types of interest (constants, formulas, comments, visible, etc.).  SpecialCells is automatically limited to the used range, which eliminates processing every single cell in a selected column, if a column is selected.  Examples range from 366 seconds without using SpecialCells, to .040 seconds by reducing selection with SpecialCells as seen on Proper, and other Text changes -- Use of Special Cells also see notations on same page.

Dimensioning variables for use with Options Explicit. (#dimensioning)  If you have simply used Dim xyz as variant you can find out the actual type that you used with  MsgBox typename(xyz)  so you can replace variant by its actual type.  (see vba.htm for more information).
```

Speeding up VBA code   (#speedupvba)

```
The biggest things were in the previous topic turning off calculation and display. Here are some additional tips.

Declare variables with their datatype [see table]:  Byte, Boolean, Long, Long, Currency, Decimal, Single, Double, Date, String, Object, Variant (default), and user-defined types, as well as specific types of objects.  A common pitfall is failing to include attributes for each variable on a DIM statement resulting in a data type of variant.

Use long in preference to integer and use double in preference to single as these are what the system actually has to use, and use String instead of Byte.  Also note that anything referring to rows should be immediately changed to long, since 65,536 exceeds the limit of the integer datatype.

Avoid changing the activecell or the active page, unless that is the desired result.  Example to create a new entry after last entry in Column A, not to be confused with last cell row (Ctrl+End), which can in itself be problematic.   (#samplesub)

 Sub SampleSub()
   Cells(Rows.Count,Range("A1").Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Value _
     ="** New Entry**"
 End Sub
```

**Does saving the file as .XLSB help at all?**

Finally, consider the following links.

http://professor-excel.com/15-ways-to-speed-up-excel/

http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/slowresp.htm

http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/17/big-trouble-in-little-spreadsheet/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx